# How do I import the JRE System Library into an existing Java project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04 and have installed openjdk-17-jdk. I also installed the extension pack for Java in VS Code. Creating a new Java project in VS Code includes the JRE System Library from the beginning.

However, when opening an existing Java project (without Maven or Gradle), libraries like java.util or java.io cannot be resolved. The project only contains "Referenced Libraries", missing the JRE System Library.

Both java.configuration.runtimes and java.home are set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64.

How do I include the JRE System Library when importing a project? How come I even have to do this?

Comment: You need to reference the JDK.  Add that as a dependency and add imports as necessary.  The target JRE is the run-time engine.

Comment: Reading the [VS Code doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project), I'm not sure how to add dependencies without Maven. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I don't use VS Code, but that link you provided has a section titled, "Configure JDK"

Comment: Both my project SDK and Java tooling runtime are set up correctly (java-17-openjdk).

Comment: you'll need the JDK (Java Development Kit).  Maybe see this link for the "Coding Pack"?: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java#_install-visual-studio-code-for-java

Comment: Is there any component missing in your installed jdk17? How about trying jdk11 instead and seeing if the question goes away?

Comment: I tried jdk8, jdk11 and jdk17 installing all components as instructed [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Java/Installation/OpenJDK/).

Comment: `Java: Clean java language server workspace` from command palette or [reset VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code). Please have a try.